# Do we want a [total-party-kill]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently noticed that we have a [total-party-kill](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/total-party-kill) tag.  It seems reasonably useful, if only to link together a bunch of related questions, but it's currently only used on [three](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/933/total-party-kill-what-do-i-do-as-a-gm) [questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53880/what-to-do-when-i-accidentally-kill-the-whole-party) (and I added it to [one of those](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71625/risk-of-a-tpk-vs-realistic-npcs)).

A few highly voted questions that perhaps *could* use this tag, but currently don't, include:

- [My PCs have a plan that will get them all killed; how and why should I save them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63594/my-pcs-have-a-plan-that-will-get-them-all-killed-how-and-why-should-i-save-them)
- [How can I prevent a TPK without obvious Deus Ex Machina?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12823/how-can-i-prevent-a-tpk-without-obvious-deus-ex-machina)
- [How can I plan a TPK finale that doesn't look planned?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/40960/how-can-i-plan-a-tpk-finale-that-doesnt-look-planned)
- [Game Over in RPGs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70651/game-over-in-rpgs)
- [How can I dissuade my players from attacking a deadly foe who isn't meant to be attacked?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56626/how-can-i-dissuade-my-players-from-attacking-a-deadly-foe-who-isnt-meant-to-be)

Should I add this tag to more questions, to make it actually useful for searching, or should I remove it from the few questions that have it?  And if the former, should [tpk](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tpk) (which currently does not exist) be made a synonym for it?

---

OK, looks like we have a fairly clear consensus that the tag should stay.  I've marked nitsua60's answer as accepted (since I can't pick more than one), and I've added the tag to the first four questions listed above, so that they can be found when searching for it.  From there on, it should be fine to let it grow organically.

Comment: 5/5 on the witty name :)

Comment: @doppelgreener: Punny titles are kind of traditional on meta questions about specific tags. [See](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal) [e.g.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306155/in-the-name-of-god) [these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284647/kill-the-player) [questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288867/assert-assert-assertion-assertions) [on](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262731/i-see-no-item-here) [meta.SO.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258700/the-website-sucks-especially-the-homepage)

Comment: Of course! And among them this one's pretty stellar

Comment: I should have said in my answer: I think a [tpk] synonym makes complete sense, too. I'd suggest it, but I don't have the requisite score in [total-party-kill].

Comment: @nitsua60: I'd have the score to suggest the synonym, but apparently the tag [tpk] would have to exist on at least one post first. If we all agree that a preemptive synonym would be a good idea, it would probably be best to get a mod to create it.

Comment: The synonym [[tag:tpk]] → [[tag:total-party-kill]] is [live now](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/total-party-kill/synonyms)!

Comment: I don't think the fifth question (which I asked) really needs this tag.  In fact, I never mentioned it in the question. I only said they can't kill an ancient dragon.  That doesn't necessarily mean it would kill all of them.

Comment: @DavidWilkins: OK, fair enough. I thought it would be useful there (particularly since I was originally looking for that very question, to link to a discussion about avoiding TPKs), but if you'd rather not have the tag there, feel free to remove it. It's your question, after all.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Keep the tag: we've got browsers, too.**

Users don't only come here when they've a specific question, but also to browse around in a repository of high-quality analysis and advice. While searching for "TPK" will likely get you a good sampling, utilizing a TPK tag would provide users another avenue to get to questions on the topic.

Comment: I use tags like this as a browser. Sometimes I recall we probably have an _excellent_ question about something I can refer someone to. If there's a tag for the topic, that makes things much easier, especially when not everyone actually uses the same terminology for this stuff: only [one question and two answers in the TPK tag](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=[total-party-kill]+total+party+kill) actually use the words "total party kill" at all, so that's 2 questions that wouldn't show up until I go rummaging through possible key words.

Comment: I also imagine and hope that sometimes, the newbies who ask about topics like this will discover our tag on it (because they applied it, or we applied it, or something) and learn about similar challenges in the same ballpark and read and become better and more knowledgeable as players and GMs and whatnot.

Comment: It's not just for casual users, either: regulars can and do use tags to find related questions. (In fact, that's what I was trying to do when I came across this tag; the specific TPK-related question I was actually looking for was [this one](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56626/how-can-i-dissuade-my-players-from-attacking-a-deadly-foe-who-isnt-meant-to-be), which I'm pretty sure I wouldn't have found using any of the obvious search keywords, if I hadn't remembered that I'd answered it myself, and so could find it through my answer history.)

Comment: I'd 1+ this for your very scientific approach and devils advocate approach but I don't want to poison the results as I don't agree with the actual argument.

Comment: Tags can also be browsed in pairs with a bit of knowledge of how to use the search feature: `[total-party-kill] [dnd-5e]` would be an effective search.

Answer (score 13):

*prepares rope swing*
*swings from balcony*

### *“Folksonomyyyyy!”*

*lands, escapes out second-storey window*

---

Tags being emergent, they don't really need ratification to continue existing. When in doubt, the default is to leave a tag alone and let it get established (or not) on its merits of utility and appeal to the site's users. They tend to only need discussion when they're trouble or potentially trouble.

This one seems to describe a particular type of problem endemic to RPGs, and appears to be not misbehaving, so it meets the minimum requirements to join the ranks of our site's tags.

As for requiring a system tag to make sense, that's an issue many of our tags share: [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells), [class-feature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-feature), and [magic-items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items) to name just a few. That's just because of the nature of our subject, where many of our questions need a system tag as well as a tag that describes the subject of the actual problem (whether that's balancing issues or handling TPKs).

In practical terms, that means go ahead and use it where it seems to fit! If nobody protests, nor identifies a subtler problem that needs meta discussion to untangle, then it's evidently fine. My personal prediction is that using it will be uncontroversial.

Comment: Was just about to comment on the question that you could also just do nothing and let it progress on its own.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith: That is certainly always an option, but it seems somewhat unsatisfactory that we have a [tag:total-party-kill] tag, but our best TPK questions aren't actually tagged with it. I'd like to do *something* about that, hence this meta question.

Answer (score -7):

**Total-Party-Kill probably wouldn't be that helpful of a tag, in fact I'd suggest scrubbing it off those three questions**

While a TPK is an RPG cliche and in some systems/tables a staple  as a grouping for questions on RPG.SE I can't see it being all that helpful. In almost every case the question ends up being very system specific because creating, avoiding, or figuring out how a TPK occurred always comes down to the balance, rules, and actions taken within the system.

To answer SevenSidedDie's valid point, I feel like [combat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combat) or [character-advancement](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-advancement) serve to highlight a specific subsection of rules you want to look at whereas TPK is so overly broad as to be non-helpful. To focus on 5e for a moment, a TPK could be caused by DM fiat ("Rocks fall, everyone dies"), a slight misundertanding/miscalculation in balancing an encounter based on CR, due to bad play/poor opitmization of the players, or as the natural outcome of a story choice made by the players.

In my opinion the tag is completely superfluous and and merely repeats information that should already be conveyed in the question title anyway.

Comment: Many of our tags are system-specific though, such as [[tag:combat]] or [[tag:character-advancement]].

Comment: @SevenSidedDie do you mean Aren't?

Comment: Combat and character advancement have games which aren't applicable, but aren't exactly system specific. Here's some better examples: [tag:fate-points], [tag:aspects], [tag:compels], [tag:create-advantage], [tag:feats], [tag:combat-maneuver], [tag:fighter], off the top of my head.

Comment: TPKs are more like [combat] than [fate-points]. You generally have to use a system tag with it as well. That's a common issue for our tags though, not something unique to [total-party-kill]. It's not really a *problem* with this tag, unless it's a problem with most of our tags.

Comment: doppelgreener sevensideddie you may both be winning me over.