# Simulacrum retagging

Tags: discussion, tags

We do have a separate tag for [simulacrum](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulacrum), and as of this morning about 48 questions were tagged with it. I did check, because I was asking a question about the origin of the spell, which an [inquiry of @nijineko](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/210811/can-fast-healing-or-regeneration-from-the-original-creature-repair-a-damaged-sim#comment580535_210812) had made me curious about. I also tagged the [most recent other questions about it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=simulacrum%20created%3A2024-03%20is%3Aquestion), that did not yet have the tag, and a couple of others, before stopping to not flood the front page with that.

The thing is, there are still [351 other questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bsimulacrum%5D%20simulacrum) that have the term simulacrum as part of their text, and that are not tagged with the [simulacrum](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulacrum) tag. From a cursory inspection, most, but not quite all of them seem to be directly about the simulacra created by spell, or about interactions of those with other game features, as described in the [simulacrum tag notes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulacrum), so most probably should have the tag.

So I'm asking the community: what should we do about it? Should we tag all these questions, in a retagging project? Or should we nix the simulacrum tag, because it seems to not add that much over just searching for "[spell] simulacrum"? Can mods autotag all the ones that are missing it, and we sort out the handful of misapplied tags manually? Or should we just do nothing?

Comment: Related: [Is the \[simulacrum\] tag a necessary addition?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11482)

Comment: "Can mods autotag all the ones that are missing it" – They can not. Mods have some built-in tools for merging/renaming/synonymizing tags, but not for bulk retagging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Sounds good...

The tag is established, it is not superfluous, so tagging the questions where relevant is appropriate. Please **make sure** to check where it **is relevant** as you go at it - **not all questions that mention it are about them.**

### Pace yourself

Please pace yourself in retagging. Depending on your time availability, two small batches or one batch per day seems appropriate so you do not flood the front page. You might not have noticed, but there was or maybe even still is a [world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness)/[chronicles-of-darkness-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-darkness-1e)/[chronicles-of-darkness-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-darkness-2e) tagging initiative by VLAZ in the last weeks, pacing out in a pair of small batches about twice a day. Please coordinate some of the *necromancy*, so we don't miss out on new content.

Comment: Just to reemphasize this, *please take care to only tag questions that are actually about the spell or the unique properties of simulacra*. There was nontrivial effort spent by several users cleaning up the [portals] tag where the tag was added to questions the tangentially mentioned portals or had answers mentioning portals, where the questions weren’t actually about portals.

Comment: Related discussion of the above: [Is there an issue with tagging questions about portals?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12455/33569)

Comment: Thanks. I did see the ongoing batches of WOD retagging.